# set column width while generating CSV using fastercsv

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fastercsv

I am using FasterCSV.generate method to generate csv. I want to set width to each column generated in csv. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. CSV doesn't have formatting metadata.